# How to configure a network interface on Ubuntu Server 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, ethernet

I would like to configure the `ethernet` network interface of a server but I am completely lost. I saw on the internet that you could do it with the `nmcli` tool but also with `netplan`, I saw some people say that you had to modify configuration files but everyone was talking about different files.

I have so far added a static IP address to the server interface by editing the `.yaml` file located in `/etc/netplan/` but now the interface has two IP addresses and I don't understand why.

So I would like to know how it is advised on Ubuntu Server 22.04 to configure a network interface and why have I now two IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, the network is administrated by `netplan`, that reads network configuration from `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Generally, the file to be configured by default is `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`.

**Important the spaces, the tabulation in `netplan` is done by groups of 2 spaces.**

An example of a typical configuration, with an `ethernet` network card in static mode would be:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.100/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.100
          on-link: True
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
  version: 2
```

Then, you must execute the commands:

```
netplan generate
netplan apply
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, also, I just saw this question https://superuser.com/a/1011511/1746203, in answers someone says to use ip which is the most modern tool rather than ifconfig. What should we use, netplan .yaml file or ip? and is there any difference between these two solutions?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the `ip` command (which of course is more modern and usable than `ifconfig`) is not permanent and would change on server restart. To avoid this, you can use `netplan`.